# JS: Callback is not a function inside if else statement

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, callback

Callback is not being recognized in the else statement of the function when compiling using google chrome. I am getting an error in my site.js file when trying to run the following code:

```
function changeSetting(callback) {
    var testswitch = document.getElementById("switch");
    if (testswitch.checked) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/ct/off/changeSetting',
            cache: false,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //No error here
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
    else if (!testswitch.checked) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/ct/on/changeSetting',
            cache: false,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //ERROR: Callback is not recognized as a function
                callback();
            }
        });
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

The only instance of this function being called is

```
changeSetting(displayEmail());
```

Uncaught Type Error: Callback is not a function

Comment: I would like to invoke the callback function though. Also deleting the () did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your function call.

```
<script>
function changeSetting(callback) {
....
}

function displayEmail() {
  return "email displayed"; // dummy value in this case 
}
</script>
```

Imagine running this code for example.

```
changeSetting(displayEmail()); // first the display email function is evaluated
```

Note that we are *invoking* the `displayEmail()` function with parantheses `()`. This means that we're going to run it and get its `return` value back, whether it be undefined, or in our case `"email displayed"`.

After evaluating the function you pass as your callback, it simplifies to something that isn't a function, hence the error. Psuedo-wise, it would "simplify" to this.

```
changeSetting("email displayed"); // "email displayed" is obviously not a function
```

To fix this, simply don't invoke the function first, pass the pointer to the function, which is simply `displayEmail`.

```
changeSetting(displayEmail);
```

Comment: What if i had a callback function of three chains?
           ``` changeSetting(function () {
                changeTemp(displayEmail);
            });```

doing that throws an error as well

Answer (score 1):

Pass only displayEmail instead of invoking it in parameter of changeSetting function

```
changeSetting(displayEmail);
```